# RIA MVVM Guidance PLEASE

Tags: mvvm, telerik, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I've been trying to implement MVVM, and for the most part I really like it.  I've been able to find answers to most of my questions, but there is one thing that either I am totally missing, or really don't get.  This is regarding data sent from the server via RIA Services.

In most examples for exposing model data in the ViewModel seem to go one of two ways, expose the entire model as a property (I don't like this approach):

```
public class MyViewModel : [SomeBaseClass]
{
    private MyModel _model;

    public MyModel Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set
        {
            if(_model == value)
                return;
            _model = value;
            PropertyChanged("MyModel");
        }
    }
}
```

OR, implement individual properties that you want to expose from the model to your view.  This is the way I have been doing it but it is a fair amount of extra work.

Many examples using a list of object show code that exposes an `ObservableCollection<TEntity>` (or some version of a generic collection) where TEntity is a class generated by RIA, then bind that to a controls ItemsSource, etc. to the collection.  Okay so far so good.  BUT what happens when I need to handle a command based on that bound object?  So far to handle this I bind to an `ObservableCollection<CustomViewModel>`.  When I get my data back from the server I loop over the returned collection and "convert" it to my CustomViewModel and put it in my collection.  Like this:

```
LoadOperation load = Context.Load(Context.GetTasksForUserQuery(userId));
load.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    if (!load.HasError)
    {
        _userTasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskItemViewModel>();

        foreach (Task entity in load.Entities)
            _userTasks.Add(new TaskItemViewModel(entity, Context));
    }
}
```

Now I have control to add command etc as needed to the TaskItemViewModel class. But this does not feel optimal.

A great example (dateded now) can be found here: [An MVVM Approach to Telerik Domain Services for Silverlight](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-12-31/an-mvvm-approach-to-telerik-domain-services-for-silverlight.aspx)
The example enables server side paging, filtering, grouping etc. and works very well.  Again it is binding to a collection of a RIA object, in this case a list of customers.  What if I want/need to handle some commands at the bound item level?

What am I missing?  I know you can have meta classes as well as shared code, but from my playing/trying it does not seem to fit the bill.  It would be so much easier to be able to just bind to the collection of `<RIAObject>`.  Is there a way to do that and have my "add-on" commands?  Any help/thought/input would be great!

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: I can see your confusion but have you thought about using CommandParameters. You can pass in `SelectedItem` from a datagrid. You can then use this bound object to perform commands or actions. There isn't really a guidance except for your experience and from others. I would say just using the list/observablecollection of entities is no problem. If you would create TaskViewModel with each of them having an entity and a context might cause memory issues if your results return more then hundreds.

Comment: Rikkos, thanks for your comment, sometimes I get so into the weeds with that I'm doing I don't look up at the big picture.  Your right, my dilemma is(was) that I have a Telerik RadGridView with a complex details view. I'm binding to the grid with a ViewModel that had all my commands etc. needed for the details.  To your point I can easily bind to the collection of TEntity then bind the details to my more "complicated"  ViewModel removing the need to have the TEntity having any commands.